# sql to r - select cases

Tags: sql, r

I have included a lot of sql code in R using the `sqldf` library. Since this is becoming increasingly hard to digest, I would like to do it using, for example `dplyr` in native R.
How would I do it for the following:

```
select v1, v2 (case when q1 > 0 then -q1 else q1 end) as v3 from dataset
```

Comment: Both sqlite and R have an abs function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset  %>% mutate(v3 = ifelse(q1>0, -q1, q1)) %>% select(v1, v2, v3)
```

Or base R:

```
dataset$v3 <- ifelse(dataset$q1 > 0,-dataset$q1, dataset$q1)
dataset[c("v1","v2","v3")]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy - but like I said, I am new to this.

Comment: `v3 = -abs(q1)`

Comment: @jogo very clever, thanks (I think OP needs to learn how to translate SQL in R so for this question I'll leave my more banal solution, but I would have liked to have your idea ahaha).

Comment: @jogo I will try to come up with better toy examples that don´t allow such tricks in the future, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
   mutate(v3 = case_when(q1 >0 ~ -q1, TRUE ~ q1)) %>%
   select(v1, v2, v3)
```